# Automating custom field value change in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have a custom field called "*Detailed Status*" in the issue page. After an issue is verified by testers, they will change the value of this field to "*Ready for Deployment*". After we deploy the latest code to the server, this should be changed to "*Verified after Deployment*".

At the moment, after every deployment there will be at least 10-15 issues which will require a developer to manually go to each issue and change the value of the custom field to "*Verified After Deployment*"

Is there a way I could automate this?

I went through the documentation - I found out the option to do a [Bulk Edit](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Modifying+Multiple+%28%27Bulk%27%29+Issues) but my project architect wouldn't hear of any manual intervention at all.
Event listeners wouldn't serve the purpose would they, since deployment is not a Jira event but an external process. Could this be done using a script ? By directly doing an update on the JIRA tables or so ?

Sorry for sounding very vague and ignorant, since I am quite new to JIRA customization. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a REST API that can be used by a script to update the custom field in the issues.

Start with http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
or 
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Edit+issues#JIRARESTAPIExample-Editissues-Examplesofupdatinganissueusingfields.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your QA takes action during the Dev process (on Dev/Test/Stage environment(s)) to verify the issue has been resolved, and again after the deployment to a Production environment.  If this is true, you could modify your workflow to allow for status & transitions to automatically set the field via a Post Function.

If QA hits 'Pass', it sends the issue forward in the workflow where that action updates the field "Detailed Status", and if they hit 'Fail/Reopen' it sends it back to Dev along with the corresponding status you want on that custom field.  This would meet the mandate of no manual intervention.

There are several free plugins that can accomplish this, and streamline your workflow so that it mirrors your development practices.